# The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all() error in Jupyter

Tags: python, jupyter

[image]

I am very new to Python and I am trying to execute the code, its giving me this error. I read its something related to Null values. can anyone tell me what I can do to fix it?

Comment: the heading of your question is not matching with the error you got

Comment: 1. The error is not "in Jupyter", because Jupyter isn't a library, it's something you use to write the code. You would get the same error when you run the code, no matter how you run it. 2. Do not post screenshots of error messages; copy and paste them, formatted as code. 3. We cannot tell you what is wrong with your code unless you show us the actual code. 4. It seems that you *are* using some libraries, such as `pandas`. You should tag those instead, so that we know what you are using and don't have to guess. 4. The error message you gave in the title does not match the error you showed.

Comment: please post your code as text rather than as picture